# Qual a melhor forma para gerar PDF com PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, pdf

Atualmente qual a melhor forma para gerar `PDF` com `PHP` usando-se `HTML` ou banco de dados?

Andei olhando umas bibliotecas, mas boa parte não tem documentação ou estão obsoletas.

O próprio `PHP` tem algo dele para tal?

Comment: Da uma olhada [aqui](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18119481/how-to-convert-a-php-web-page-to-pdf).

Comment: Bom dia! Como eu disse, a mPDF está descontinuada desde 2016. Portando não acho prudente investir em algo que não terei suporte. O sistema aqui é grande e crítico, não podemos correr riscos...

Comment: Por outro lado, no mesmo artigo tem uma citação a outros dois projetos que parecem ser bem robustos.

jsPDF = https://parall.ax/products/jspdf

TCPDF = https://tcpdf.org

OBS: esse último tem documentação muito superior...